# JBoss EAP 6.4 Log4J 1.2.17 Errors

Tags: java, logging, log4j, migration, jboss-eap-6

I am trying to configure Log4J 1.2.17 for JBoss EAP 6.4 and keep getting

ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.

I was not having this problem with EAP 6.2 and not sure what to do. The only support I could find was a migration guide but that didn't help much because everything it said to change I had already configured.

Comment: Did you add the log4j jar in the class path of your project ?

Comment: yes. and I had it working in EAP 6.2. And the migration documentation suppported from JBoss wan't any help either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my problem. I orginally defined my dependency in my MANIFEST.MF like so:

```
Dependencies: org.apache.log4j
```

With this defined I get the above error. However when I remove this entry from my MANIFEST.MF and add the dependency to a jboss-deployment-structure.xml:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name ="org.apache.log4j"/>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

My problem is resolved. Not sure if this is a bug or if it works as designed in EAP 6.4. I also tested that this solution is backwards compatible to EAP 6.2.

Comment: Unless you're explicitly excluding it, you shouldn't need to add a log4j dependency to your deployment. The dependency should automatically be added during deployment.

Comment: I wish that were true. Without that line in the dependencies all I received were class not found exceptions in both EAP 6.2 and EAP 6.4

Comment: Have you removed the logging subsystem? If not it should definitely be adding the dependency.

Comment: FYI - check the [JBoss Windup migration tool](https://github.com/windup/windup/wiki). It would be great if you could contribute a rule for your case.